# Importing C++ file in python

Tags: c++, python-2.7

Is there a way to directly import C++ file in python file without converting C++ into DLL for e.g.

```
import CPP_file.cpp
import os
.
.
.
```

Comment: and how would python compile the cpp code?

Comment: True ..I know it won't be possible without DLL but just wanted to know if there is any wrapper or something to do so ?

Comment: There are several ways to interface Python with C++, but textual inclusion will certainly not work.

Comment: I am trying to use boost.python(https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/SimpleExample)  but thing is even that will require me build c++ wrapper for python

Comment: You may like also https://github.com/wjakob/pybind11. I like this better as this is not dependent on Boos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. C++ code needs to be compiled!
There are different ways for embeddind c++ code in your python but they will all need you C++ code to be compiled in a sort of library!

one technology that you can use for example is SWIG:

http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html

another alternative is to use Boost Python Library. Here a short description taken from their web page:

> The Boost Python Library is a framework for interfacing Python and
>   C++. It allows you to quickly and seamlessly expose C++ classes
>   functions and objects to Python, and vice-versa, using no special
>   tools -- just your C++ compiler. It is designed to wrap C++ interfaces
>   non-intrusively, so that you should not have to change the C++ code at
>   all in order to wrap it, making Boost.Python ideal for exposing
>   3rd-party libraries to Python. The library's use of advanced
>   metaprogramming techniques simplifies its syntax for users, so that
>   wrapping code takes on the look of a kind of declarative interface
>   definition language (IDL).